# How do I assign a function to a variable?

Tags: python

I'm creating a text game so here is the point where I got stuck at:

```
def characters():

    def assassin():
        dmg = 150
        health = 500

print "Do you want to become an assassin ?"
choice = raw_input("> ")

if choice in ["Yes", "yes", "YES"]:
    print "So you said %s about becoming an assassin" % choice
    choice = assassin() # Error
else:
    print "Templar detected!"
```

So I wanted to set the choice variable to the assassin() function and then I wanted to copy the properties of the assassin() function to the choice variable but all I get is error that says " assassin is not defined.".

So, how can I do that ?

Comment: See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125); your `choice` test won't work as written.

Comment: Your `characters` function doesn't do anything.  Did you mean to have all the rest of the code inside `characters` as well?

Comment: Is this supposed to be OOP? Perhaps look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: The local variables in your `assassin` function are not going to be assessable, apart from the fact that that function is inside another function that you didn't call.

Comment: The error is obvious when you read the documentation - the part about name resolution in Python. `assassin` is a local function in `characters` and thus is visible only inside that function. Beside that, it is completely unclear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: You could use a class for that kind of thing however, but you shouldn't put that class inside a function still.

Comment: Oh yeah, perhaps you typed `def` when you wanted `class`?

Comment: Your if statement could use some attention. `if choice.upper() == "YES"` would take care of all case issues.

Comment: @BrenBarn my `characters` function will include many functions inside of it

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm learning python from a book called **Learn python the hard way**  so i didn't get to the OOP part, I'm limited to functions only

Comment: @MartijnPieters so i must call the 'Characters' function first then call 'assassin' function ?

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm trying to organize the code so that function 'characters' will include many kinds of characters including 'assassin' function i was testing the code to make sure that everything is alright and then i would continue coding

Comment: @Marwan Please re-read the chapter about functions and their purpose. You seem to have misunderstood it, and it's really hard to guess what are you trying to achieve exactly with these functions. The task you're solving doesn't really need local functions, and your functions don't do anything. We really would like to help, but there seems we would even have trouble finding some common ground to communicate.

Comment: @User Thank you i will use that function now

Comment: @Marwan: `characters` doesn't do anything with the `assassin` function; neither function returns anything.

Comment: @BartoszKP ok Thank you i will re-read the chapter

Comment: @MartijnPieters so if i did delete the `characters` function would the code work then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

`if choice == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES":` doesn't do what you think it does.

In Python, `x or y` always returns `True` or `False` based on the values of `x` and `y`. 
The Python intepreter inteprets that line different to how it would be intepreted in English.

It means the same as this `if (choice == "Yes") or ("yes") or ("YES")`.
As a non-empty string has the Boolean value `True`, this is the same as `if (choice == "Yes") or True or True`. The first part of that - `(choice == "Yes") or True` has `True` as an argument to the `or`, so it (and therefore the whole line) will always be `True`.

The second problem is that you are misunderstanding how functions work.
Firstly, neither of these functions do anything. A function is a way of giving a name to some code, which makes your program shorter if you are calling it more than once.

Secondly, variables in a function definition (and functions defined inside others) aren't accessible outside the function. That is why the variable `assassin` isn't located outside the definition of the `characters` function.

Answer (score 0):

The *assassin* function doesn't do anything other than assigning the variables *dmg* and *health* some values.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to set the variables inside that function to a new variable , how do i do that ?

Comment: @Marwan You can't do that, and you shouldn't want to do that :)

Comment: @BartoszKP i figured out now haha

Comment: So, what did you figure out?

Comment: @MagnusN i figured out that functions only work when they are called beacause its a block of code that can be called when you want .. so my epic mistake was trying to treat a function as a class but now i got it